# Access inner class variables

Tags: c#, class

How can I access members of an inner class?
For example.

```
class A
{
    class B
    { 
      public int X;
    }
}

class C
{
  // any possible way to summon int x here ?
}
```

What I want to do is summon the integer X inside of Class C. How can I do this? 
Is the only way is this?

```
class A
{

}


class B
{ 
     public int X;
}

class C
{
  //summonning int x here
}
```

Comment: You want to use `x` in between classes?

Comment: You either make X static or you create an *instance* of the class `B`. Read up on classes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx) and static [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

Comment: @GregaMohorko yes i mean use by summoning

Comment: You need to 1) case the word `class` in lower case otherwise it will not compile. 2) scope your classes correctly so that class B is visible outside of class A. 3) Then refer  to class B just as you would any other class but when you reference it you have to prefix it with the class it is nested in, example `var b = new A.B();`

Comment: @YvetteColomb of course as long as it gives the right meaning

Comment: Side note C# is not Java... Make sure to read on the differences in nested classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the inner class public
and some more reading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx

```
public class A
{
        public Class B
        { 
          public int X;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make your classes A and B public.
Then,

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new C().X);
    }

}
public class A
{
    public class B
    { 
        public int X;
        public B(){
            X = 5;
        }
    }
}

public class C{
  public int X {get;set;}
  public C(){
    var objB = new A.B();
    X = objB.X;   
  }
}
```

Thanks you @Default!  I should use fiddle a lot more often rather than blindly writing.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing non-static fields can only be done with instances of that class. Check the example below. It gets the non-static `X` field from an instance of `A.B` and a static field `Y` from inner `B` class directly.

```
public class A
{
    public class B
    { 
        public int X;
        public static int Y;
    }
}
public class C
{
    void Function1(A.B instanceOfB){
        int x=instanceOfB.X; // get value of non-static field X
        int y=A.B.Y; // get value of static field Y
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class ShopCart
    {
        public class ShopCartPosition
        {
            private int _number;

            public int Number
            {
                get { return _number; }
                set { _number = value; }
            }

        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        ShopCart.ShopCartPosition _shopCartPosition;
        public User(ShopCart.ShopCartPosition shopCartPosition)
        {
            _shopCartPosition = shopCartPosition;
        }

        public int GetNumber()
        {
            return _shopCartPosition.Number;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        ShopCart.ShopCartPosition pos = new ShopCart.ShopCartPosition();
        pos.Number = 5;

        User user = new User(pos);

        Console.WriteLine(user.GetNumber().ToString());
    }
```

Here you can do it using dependency injection. Don't use A,B,C it is annoying. You can check what is SOLID and why it is good to use dependency injection.

Comment: @YvetteColomb he had public int X in his code. So I wanted to show him that he should made it private and use properties.

Comment: @mybirthname i just used A, B, C for simplicity while previewing but of course i never use them i use what fits for my original code